# Any work-around for the lack of XMLSignature implementations?

Tags: crypto, encryption, decrypt

As explained in this [unimplemented for 4 years idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IA4gAAG), Apex does not expose any [XMLSignature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/XMLSignature.html) implementations that could be used for example to validate the X509 signature on some XML.

So:

1. Does Apex have sufficient building blocks e.g. methods of the [Crypto class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) to allow an XMLSignature implementation (or equivalent) to be written in Apex?
2. If the answer to 1) is **yes**, does anyone know of an open source or commercial implementations available anywhere? Or will I have to write one myself?
3. If the answer to 1) is **no**, is calling out to e.g a Heroku service to do the work a reasonable alternative?

**PS** I've just seen but not digested yet this [XML Signature thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008wSGIAY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went ahead and built a state-less Heroku web service that makes use of [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home) to do all the signature related work.